# Simple way in ruby to ignore error if object doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two objects: Wine, Brand

```
Brand has_many :wines
Wine belongs_to :brand
```

How can I simplify the following code:

```
<%= @wine.brand.name if @wine.brand %>
```

I realize it's already very simple, but I have some different complexities in my code that make this cumbersome. What I'd like to do is something along the lines of:

```
<%= &@wine.brand.name %>
```

Where it basically ignores the error. In PHP you can do this, I just can't find a corollary for ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`try`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try) method:

```
<%= @wine.brand.try(:name) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather do this as follows:

```
class Wine  
  def brand_name
    brand.present? ? brand.name : ''
  end
end
```

This keeps your view slightly cleaner:

```
<%= @wine.brand_name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate):

```
class Wine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  delegate :name, to: :brand, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

This creates a `Wine#brand_name` method, returning either the brand's `name` or `nil` if brand does not exist.